# Installing TYPO3 v10.1, Apache2 says it needs PHP >=7.2 - <=7.4, but 7.3 is installed according to php -v

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-10.x

Exactly as stated in the title. I installed [TYPO3 v10.1](https://typo3.org) using [PHP Composer](https://getcomposer.org) as stated in the [Installation Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/). How can I get the TYPO3 installer to recognise the correct version of PHP?

As Debian 9 (Stretch) comes with PHP 7.0 by default, I had to configure the correct package repository in order to install an up-to-date version of PHP (in my case PHP 7.3) but the TYPO3 installer does not use this version.

However, the following command shows the correct version 7.3:

```
php -v
```

Comment: PHP CLI is not the same as the PHP Apache module, to see which PHP version apache is using, use the `phpinfo();` method. You need to change the PHP version in your apache seting, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/895746/switch-from-php-7-2-to-7-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-apache) might help.

Comment: This will probably help you: https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-debian/

Comment: You can use the platform option on composer: https://blog.liplex.de/force-composer-to-use-specific-php-version/amp/

Comment: Thanks to all for contributions. None of them worked. Now switching to a server with greater flexibility so I can use current Arch instead of an outmoded Debian version. Aristeidis, composer.json already had v7.2 in its config.